# Multi label with mulit placement in OpenLayers

Tags: labeling, style, openlayers-2

I have a vector layer in `OpenLayers`. It has some attributes like `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, etc.
I want every feature to be multi-label (to have more than one label).
The javascript code is as follows:

```
style = new OpenLayers.Style();
rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
    filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({...}),
    symbolizer: {
        fillColor: 'blue',
        label: ?????,
    }
});

style.addRules([rule]);

styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    'default': style
});


myLayer.styleMap = styleMap
```

I want my style to be like this:
[image]

**How do I do?**

> **note**: I know that I will be able to do this by **"SLD"**, but I have to use style map in OpnenLayers.

Comment: I don't know openLayers well enough to answer; buy [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/vector-labels.html) seems to take a different approach from the symbolizer. In particular see the `createTextStyle` function and the `offset` parameter. That is you can create 4 text labels, one for each field while modifying location using offset.x and offset.y

Answer (score 1):

The label is a SVG text element. I suggest you to make an override for `OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.prototype.drawText` function.

Open your OpenLayers install package and find it here: `lib\OpenLayers\Renderer\SVG.js:649`

Take the function and override it in your own code like this:

```
// My drawText override
OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.prototype.drawText = function (featureId, style, location) {
// Original code here
}
```

The override must be read later than the OpenLayers library by the browser.
In the override, you have to test whether the `style` object contains your additive attributes like `left`, `top`, or whatever you name it and if yes, apply a transform to the label. For left, it will be

```
 var translate = 'translate(' + -shift + ',' + 0 + ')';
 label.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", translate);
```

where `shift` is desired shift in pixels.

I did similar override for label rotation, but your case is a bit more complicated, because if I understood right, you want to be able to add four labels for one feature. It means your override will have to be able add four labels instead of one.

Comment: Can you put an answer?

Answer (score -1):

I'm interested in the response of this because i had the same problem.

I solved it(but it's not really a good solution) publishing several Vectors using the same entring data and giving them a different style.

Comment: You can use SLD. Follow this page: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/sld.html